# How does one install skyrim from steamcmd?

Tags: steam, steamcmd

I am having trouble downloading skyrim from steamcmd. Below is the following problem. How does one install skyrim from steamcmd?

```
steam@ger:~/stemcmd$ ./steamcmd.sh +login bcommeau +force_install_dir ../skyrim +app_update 72850 +quit
Redirecting stderr to '/home/steam/.local/share/Steam/logs/stderr.txt'
[  0%] Checking for available updates...
[----] Verifying installation...
Steam Console Client (c) Valve Corporation
-- type 'quit' to exit --
Loading Steam3...OK.

Logging in user 'linuxfreebird' to Steam Public...Using cached credentials. . .
Success.
ERROR! Failed to install app '72850' (Invalid platform)
```

Comment: Just a guess.... are you sure that Skyrim is available for Linux? The `(Invalid Platform)` bit seems to indicate that its not...

Comment: Skyrim only supports windows. You can't install windows games through Linux steam whether you're using the graphical client or steamcmd.

Comment: I have PLayonlinux. Am I supposed to use this somehow in playonlinux?

Comment: @linuxfreebird PlayOnLinux is a wrapper around Wine. Using POL just automates the procedure of installing the *windows* version of Steam via Wine and running it. You could probably then install windows Steamcmd and use that, but at that point it's easier to just use the graphical windows steam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch to Windows. *Maybe* Wine.

Seriously. Even if you have a way to get Skyrim running on another OS, the official Steam store page lists the following requirement:

[image: Skyrim OS Requirement]

One of the things Steam (whether through the UI version, or the command line version) does, is check some of the system requirements, including OS. Unless they start officially supporting Linux, you're gonna keep getting an Invalid Platform error. Folks have requested a flag for steamcmd to ignore the OS before (for things like just downloading an update's files to send to several systems), but it's never materialized.

You *might* be able to get away with [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/) instead. I've personally never gone down the Wine route on a Linux system, since I always have a Windows gaming PC, but Wine does make Steam think you're running on Windows. The thing is, while it should convince the GUI version of Steam download games despite the platform issue, I have no idea whether steamcmd will work properly under it. And I have no idea what it will take from there to get it running.

Answer (score 1):

`steamcmd` supports forcing platform type to avoid this issue (I just used it to grab Stanley Parable Demo files for Linux) with `@sSteamCmdForcePlatformType` so try:

```
steam@ger:~/stemcmd$ ./steamcmd.sh +login bcommeau +@sSteamCmdForcePlatformType windows +force_install_dir ../skyrim +app_update 72850 +quit
```

Further useful information is here https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/SteamCMD